# Regular Expression to parse out anchor tag's href

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have html code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="seller0-showAllImage" onclick="showPlusBox(0,'/products/plusbox?cid=9286328115358229395&amp;authorid=2860562')" class="fl">
```

in result I need to have only string:

```
/products/plusbox?cid=9286328115358229395&amp;authorid=2860562
```

How can I match it in RegEx from the html code?
Thanks!

Comment: Not enough information. In this example, the regex `'(.*)'` would already be enough, but it would break if there could be more than one instance of single quotes in your text.

Comment: As I understand regular expressions, they're good for patterns. If all you need is that string, you already have it... If you also want to be able to match others, then it would be good to provide a bit more information about what the other things you're trying to match look like. Do they always start with /products/? Do they always end in authorid=#?

Comment: In which context are you processing the data?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Why did you remove the NSRegularExpression tag? It was the only clue that the OP wants to do it in Objective-C.

Comment: @sidyll: I though it might be a mistake because I saw another question where this tag was used mistakenly (people start typing `regulare...` and the first tag in the list is `nsregularexpression`). But you are right, maybe he really wants to use Objective-C (rollback) (though the history of questions does not support this thought).

Comment: I need extract that string: /products/plusbox?cid=9286328115358229395&authorid=2860562

Comment: @Felix Kling: Right. So it's better to wait more clarification… Ah, regarding typing it and NSRegularExpression appearing as first result was very well noticed!

Comment: @ihorko: More importantly: Are you really doing this in Objective-C or in some other language? What is the context? Do you have the HTML as string or are you even working in the browser? It is not at all clear what the context is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match:

```
showPlusBox(0,'([^']+)')
```

Reference `$1` is then the string you're looking for.

Of course, this depends pretty much on the exact strings you want to match; where it's embedded, etc. With a single example there isn't much to extrapolate. Honestly, the Regex

```
/products/plusbox\?cid=9286328115358229395&amp;authorid=2860562
```

would also match what you're looking for, for example.

Comment: +1, but editing before the 5 min to match what I posted is cheating! :-) Just kidding

Comment: I saw what you posted only after I edited it ;-). It was a natural thing to point out, actually. Note though, that you first need to replace the HTML entities, otherwise nothing will be matched :-)

Comment: Hmm, strange because I was sure I had copied the string. Maybe the formatting ate the `amp`, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: sidyll: Urgh, nevermind. They actually want the string from the HTML, not the relative URI it represents.

Answer (score 2):

This regex:

```
/products/plusbox\?cid=9286328115358229395&authorid=2860562
```

Matches it.

If you want a more generic expression, please provide more info.